# nmap unable to split netmask from target expression

Tags: domain-name-system, nmap

I'm trying to scan my website with nmap to see what is visible from outside...but
nmap returns this value...

```
Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-05-06 01:06 PDT
Unable to split netmask from target expression: "https://website"
WARNING: No targets were specified, so 0 hosts scanned.
Nmap done: 0 IP addresses (0 hosts up) scanned in 0.03 seconds
```

I tried  using several different flags but I'm getting same message...
Anyone know how to deal with this?
And yes, my website is visible from outside, my friends were able to visit my website

P.S It looks like I can't ping the server by hostname as well.

Comment: What was the command line you used?

Answer (score 4):

NMap uses hostnames / IP addresses to scan hosts, but you used an URL, which includes the protocol also.

Try using simply `nmap website`.